# How to assign element values inside jquery.each() function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a php page which calls a javascript function to populate it.
The page is a list of users each with their own form, the form id has the id appended to its name to allow edit, delete etc on each user.
The form is is the shape of an html page that is in theory sucked in for each record.
I am using jquery each() to iterate over the records, then in theory the html page should be sucked in and populated for each record. I have tried for loop also.
The code below produces the correct number of forms but empty.
Other efforts have left me with only the last record populating the fist box and the others empty.
Any help greatly appreciated.

```
$(Udata).each(function(uId, value){
    uid = value.uid;
    var uname = value.uname;
    function setValues() {
       window.document.getElementById("username").value=uname;
       window.document.getElementById("frmDelUsr").setAttribute("name","frmDelUsr"+uid);
    }

    $.get("users.html",{}, function (data) {                            
    $("#divfrmDelUser").append(data), function(){setValues();}

});
```

Comment: jQuery will only find  the first field with id in your dom it assumes id will be unique. Use classes and see tell separate them by parrent

Answer (score 0):

```
$(Udata).each(function(uId, value){
    uid = value.uid;
    var uname = value.uname;
    function setValues() {
       window.document.getElementById("username").value=uname;
       window.document.getElementById("frmDelUsr").setAttribute("name","frmDelUsr"+uid);
    }

    $.get("users.html",{}, function (data) {                            
    $(this).children('.divfrmDelUser').append(data), function(){setValues();} //<--- CHANGED

});
```

First you'd have to change the element with the ID "divfrmDelUser" by making that ID into a class(just erase "id" and type "class" obviously), then what this ought to do is select the current Udata being used, and then look for the elements within it containing the class "divfrmDelUser" and do what you set it to do past that.

Comment: Thanks for swift reply, I have now but to no avail. I want to use the value rather than innerHTML when user deletes or edits

Comment: Ah yes, I completely forgot, what @Filip was saying is something I didn't pay attention to(was busy when writing that), but that is why it only populates the first one. I guess I could make an example of it here for you if you haven't figured it out already.

Comment: I got what Filip meant and have adjusted accordingly. I changed my code and id as you suggested however it does not fire the setValues() function.